# Maximum size when parsing XML with DOM

Tags: java, android, xml

Currently I'm implementing a REST client which shall parse the XML response messages. It is intended, later, to be running on an Android device. Thus, memory and processing speed is quite an issue. However there will be only one XML response at a time so processing or holding multiple XML documents at a time is not an issue.

As fas as I understood there are three ways of parsing XML with the Android SDK:

- SAX
- XmlPullParser
- DOM

Reading about these different parsing methods I got that SAX is recommended for large XML files as it won't hold the complete tree in memory like DOM.

However, I'm asking myself what is large in terms of kilobytes, megabytes, ...? Is there a practical size up to which it does not really matter whether using SAX or DOM?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Actually for processing large XML documents, VTD-XML is more efficient and user friendly than SAX or DOM...

Comment: vtd is efficient, i think it's a good alternative

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no standard limits set for XML documents or DOM size so it depends entirely on what the host machine can cope with.

As you are implementing on Android you should assume a pretty limited amount of memory, and remember the DOM, the XML parser, your program logic, the display logic, the JVM  and Android itself all have to fit in the available memory!.

As a rule of thumb you can expect the DOM occupy memory about four times the size of the source XML document. So assume 512MB of available memory, aim to take no more than half of this for you DOM and you end up with 512/8 or a practical maximum of 64MB for the XML doc.

Just to be on the safe side I would half that again to a 32MB max. So if you expect many documents of this size I would swithc to SAX parsing!.

If you want the app to respond with any speed on large documents the SAX is the way to go. A SAX parser can start returning results as soon as the first element is read a DOM parser needs to read the whole document before any output can be sent to your program.

Comment: James, thanks a lot for your explanation! I'm expecting that the XML document will have a maximum file size of about 30-50 kB which should be possible handling with DOM. However it seems as if implementing a SAX parser will be a better "overall solution".

Comment: VTD-XML may be another option worth considering, if performance and memory are important aspect of application performance, its memory usage is about 1/3 of DOM on 32 bit system, and it natively supports XPath

Answer (score 4):

Excerpt from [this article](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/android-services-part-2?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+javalobby%2Ffrontpage+%28Javalobby+%2F+Java+Zone%29):

> DOM parsers suffer from memory bloat.  With smaller XML sets this isn't such an issue but as the XML size grows DOM parsers become less and less efficient making them not very scaleable in terms of growing your XML. Push parsers are a happy medium since they allow you to control parsing, thereby eliminating any kind of complex state management since the state is always known, and they don't suffer from the memory bloat of DOM parsers.

This could be the reason SAX is recommended over DOM: SAX functions as an XML push parser. Also, check out the Wikipedia article for SAX [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML#Benefits).

EDIT: To address size specifically you would have to look at your implementation. An example of DOM `Document` object size in the memory of a Java-based XML parser is [here](http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch09s05.html). Java, like a lot of languages, defines some memory-based limitations such as the [JVM heap size](http://www.informix-zone.com/node/46), and the Android web services/XML DOM API may also define some internal limits at the programmers' discretion (mentioned in part [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setFeature%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)). There is no one definitive answer as to maximum allowed size.

Comment: Yes, however my core question is for up to which size (file size, number of elements, etc.) DOM can be used without worrying too much about its memory overhead? As the article says "With smaller XML sets this isn't such an issue [...]". But what does "smaller" mean?

Answer (score 2):

My experience let me say that using DOM the memory used is 2x the file size, but of course it's just an indication. If the XML tree has just one field containing the entire data, the memory used is similar to file size!