# Max size of xml for Dom parser

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I´m making android app. As ussual i´m storing my data in xml file(i´m used to do that), I have DOM parser to get these data into my app. Now i have this problem, i was working only with partial xml and everything was fine. When i filled my xml completely (its about 6000 rows and 375kb size, i will probably need even more) i´m getting this error:

```
08-03 17:01:36.429    3866-3866/com.example.blackess.smstestas E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:952)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I thought that i have some bad value or something wrong in my xml, but after i searched for that problem i find out that when i have xml under 5000 rows my program is working but if i add more even tested data my program will crash.

What could be that problem or how can i fix it?

Edit: Was reading this [Maximum size when parsing XML with DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182355/maximum-size-when-parsing-xml-with-dom) too, thought with my 375kb i ´m in limit.

Comment: did you try using SAX parser like everyone in that link suggests for large xml files?

Comment: I will do that i guess. Wanted to ask first if that will even help me, because it looks like i shuold be able to that this way too and i don´t wanna spend that time with rewriting parser if that might not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn´t with xml size, that worked fine. Problem was with the size of intent. There should be possible to pass about 1Mb but it seems i was over this value.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your `XML`, so check it with an external parser or debug it to see which line/attribute is broken into the XML and causes the `NullPointerException`.

About memory limit, you're far from limit, you should have only 750Kb of memory to have problems with a 375Kb file, and parsing the file wont be the problem... eclipse won't even open with this lack of memory...

Comment: I ´m using android studio. I see that NullPointerExc too, but i´m not able find that problem as i described. I have 5000 rows xml working and when i add more data it will drop, but if i remove all these previous data and add only this last added thing it works so i really dont know how to find the problem

Comment: Yeah one more try, the border of 5000 rows is cursed...under that everything wokrs but if i have more than that it will crash.